# Authentication of ASP.NET Web API before login

Tags: angular, webapi

I have one API that returns all localization data(English and Spanish) to the Angular application. Here the user is not logged in when I call this localization API. so I don't have any way to authenticate the request. I tried to use API-Key but this API-Key is visible in the Angular main.js file so I can't go with that option.

I am thinking to use the domain and host from the header to verify the source of API call.

I don't know whether it is the right solution to problem.

Could anyone please let me know what should I do in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand your problem, but can't you have 2 endpoints to retrieve the localized data, one for authenticated users (if that is even necessary) and another for unauthenticated users (to render the login UI for instance). Using the domain, host or even the user agent isn't going to protect anything.

Comment: @DavidFontes, I am retrieving localization data from endpoint. Like when the user hit the website at that time in the background angular will call the endpoint and load data into Angular components to display labels/text on the screen. I want to secure this open endpoint.  Currently, I am using API-Key authentication, environment.ts(where I am keeping API-Key) file is loaded with javascript source code. We can see API-Key in the main.js file. Is there any alternative way through which I can secure this endpoint?

Comment: I understood as much, but you are not giving us enough details about your problem. From what I understand, if you **need** to have the endpoint secured, and you **can't** have the user authenticated, then there isn't much you can do, though I'm no expert, so I will let this one to someone else.